# ng g c c-name => Specified module does not exist

Tags: angular, angular-cli, angular-cli-v6

#### My current dir

`/src/app`

#### app.module.ts dir

`/src/app/app.module.ts`

#### I need a new component in this dir

`catalog/single/configurator/[new component here]`

#### trying to add a component #1

`ng g c catalog/single/configurator/details-popout --module AppModule`

> Specified module does not exist

#### trying to add a component #2

`ng g c catalog/single/configurator/details-popout --module /app.module`

> Invalid rule result: Function().

#### trying to add a component #3

`ng g c catalog/single/configurator/details-popout --module app`

> Invalid rule result: Function().

---

## Question

How can i add the component `details-popout` with Angular CLI?

#### Env

```
Angular CLI: 6.0.8
Node: 9.2.0
OS: darwin x64
Angular: 6.1.7
... animations, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... http, language-service, platform-browser
... platform-browser-dynamic, platform-server, router
... service-worker

Package                           Version
-----------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect         0.6.8
@angular-devkit/build-angular     0.6.8
@angular-devkit/build-optimizer   0.6.8
@angular-devkit/core              0.6.8
@angular-devkit/schematics        0.7.5
@angular/cli                      6.0.8
@angular/fire                     5.0.0
@angular/pwa                      0.6.8
@ngtools/webpack                  6.0.8
@schematics/angular               0.7.5
@schematics/update                0.6.8
rxjs                              6.3.2
typescript                        2.7.2
webpack                           4.8.3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ng g c catalog/single/configurator/details-popout --module app.module.ts`

> Allows specification of the declaring module's file name (e.g
>   `app.module.ts`).

[Doc is here](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/generate-component)

**The real problem was:**

Make sure your's `@angular/cli` package is updated to the last version running:

```
npm install -g @angular/cli
```

Comment: that resulted in `Invalid rule result: Function().`

Comment: you need to place the full path of the module... I dont know you have to get back 2 folders or three, but you need to place from you are to the target module

Comment: closer => `Path "//src/app/../../../app.module.ts" is invalid.`

Comment: if you are already in the path of `app.module.ts` you need to write this: `ng g c catalog/single/configurator/details-popout --module app.module.ts`

Comment: hmm I am in already in the `app` dir... So the path to the module should be `./app.module.ts` but i got the error `Invalid rule result: Function().`.... Do i need to change setting allow paths to modules? I think it would work if it were allowed

Comment: here worked `--module app.module.ts` and  `--module ./app.module.ts`... cli version? try to run `npm install -g @angular/cli` again..

Comment: thats it... I had to `npm install -s @angular/cli`

Comment: maybe was failing cause missing global  `-g` or something else that i can't figure it out :) it's working that's great

Comment: Local angular was not the latest... global was fine

Comment: if you write in the answer that to update the cli then il mark it as correct